# Creating a dictionary with calculated values

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, counter

I have a large text string and I would like to create a dictionary with a key = a pair of words (have to go through all possible combinations) in the string and the value = frequency of a given pair of words. Thus, it is a 2D matrix and each matrix element is a number (a frequency of the pair from a column and a row crossing each other. The position of the words in the pair is irrelevant: e.g. if ridebike = 4 (a frequency) then bikeride = 4 as well

The end result is to populate the matrix and then select N number of top pairs.

I am new working with text strings and with Python in general and I got hopelessly lost (also way too many loops in my "code")

This is what I have (after deleting stopwords and punctuations):

```
textNP = 'stopped traffic bklyn  bqe  278 wb manhattan brtillary stx29  wb  cadman pla  hope  oufootball makes safe manhattan kansas tomorrow  boomersooner  beatwildcats  theyhateuscuztheyaintus  hatersgonnahate rt  bringonthecats  bring cats exclusive  live footage oklahoma trying get manhattan  http  colktsoyzvvz rt  jonfmorse  bring cats exclusive  live footage oklahoma trying get manhattan'
```

Some code (incomplete and wrong):

```
txtU = set(textNP)
lntxt = len(textNP)
lntxtS = len(txtU)

matrixNP = {}

for b1, i1 in txtU: 
    for b2, i2 in txtU:
        if i1< i2:
            bb1 = b1+b2
            bb2 = b2+b1

            freq = 0

            for k in textNP:
                for j in textNP:
                    if k < j:

                        kj = k+j
                        if kj == bb1 | kj == bb2:

                            freq +=1

            matrixNP[i1][i2] = freq
            matrixNP[i2][i1] = freq

        elif i1 == i2: matrixNP[i1][i1] = 1
```

One of the issues that I am certain that having many loops is wrong. Also, I am not sure how to assign calculated keys (concatenation of words) to a dictionary (I think I got the values correctly)

The text string is not a complete product: it will be cleaned from numbers and few other things with various regexs

Your help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for all combinations of 2 words, if so you can use `itertools.combinations` and a `collections.Counter` to do what you want:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> N = 5
>>> c = Counter(tuple(sorted(a)) for a in combinations(textNP.split(), 2))
>>> c.most_common(N)
[(('manhattan', 'rt'), 8),
 (('exclusive', 'manhattan'), 8),
 (('footage', 'manhattan'), 8),
 (('manhattan', 'oklahoma'), 8),
 (('bring', 'manhattan'), 8)]
```

Or are you looking for all pairs of consecutive words then you can create a pairwise function:

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     a, b = tee(iterable)
...     next(b, None)
...     return zip(a, b)    # itertools.izip() in python2
>>> N = 5
>>> c = Counter(tuple(sorted(a)) for a in pairwise(textNP.split()))
>>> c.most_common(N)
[(('get', 'manhattan'), 2),
 (('footage', 'live'), 2),
 (('get', 'trying'), 2),
 (('bring', 'cats'), 2),
 (('exclusive', 'live'), 2)]
```

Neither way do I see bike ride in the list.

Comment: what is repeat = 2 for, if you do not mind mine asking? What you are saying that I do not have to create the matrix?

Comment: `repeat=2` takes the list of words and picks all combinations of 2 (pairs).

Comment: This does effectively build a matrix, but flattened into a dictionary like object using the coordinate ('word1', 'word2') as the key and the count as the value

Comment: Also one issue here is that "manhattan", "manhattan" has a frequency of 16. This does not mean that this PAIR exists in a given text 16 times (most likely it is only a word "manhattan" is there 16 times. All such pairs must have a real frequency or just 1. How can this be changed? Also I could not find a pair "manhattan", "oklahoma" 8 times in this text.

Comment: Probably `itertools.combinations` is a better match - replaced

Comment: the second way is the solution! Thank you. It is great! How do I formalize it in a dictionary where the key = a pair of words?

Comment: `Counter` is already a dictionary as in you can do `for k, v in c.items():` etc. but if you need a vanilla `dict` then just `dict(c)`